# How to find Kendo grid column in jQuery function?

Tags: c#, jquery, model-view-controller, kendo-grid

I wanted to find the Kendo Gridview column and check so that I can use it for validation.

I have the following Kendo Grid definition:

```
Html.Kendo().Grid(Model.lstApproveCustReadList)
    .Name("ApproveCustomerMeterRead")

    .Columns(
        column => {
            column.Bound(e => e.REGISTRATION_ID).Width(40).ClientTemplate(" <input id='#= REGISTRATION_ID #' type='checkbox' class='chkSel' value='#= REGISTRATION_ID #'/>").Title("Approve").Filterable(false).Locked(true).Sortable(false);
            //column.Bound(e => e.NAME).Title("Name");
            column.Bound(e => e.NAME).Width(150).Title("Name").ClientTemplate("<a href='javascript: void(0);' onclick=\"return fn_RegistrationDetailsList('#=REGISTRATION_ID#','R');\">#= NAME#</a>").HtmlAttributes(new {
                @class = "faContainer", title = " #=NAME# "
            });
            column.Bound(e => e.MPAN).Title("MPAN");
            column.Bound(e => e.NORMAL_METER_READ).Title("Normal meter read");
            column.Bound(e => e.LOW_METER_READ).Title("Low meter read");
            column.Bound(e => e.METER_READ_DATE).Title("Read date");
            column.Bound(e => e.SETTLEMENT_DATE_REGI).Title("Settlement date");
            column.Bound(e => e.REGISTRATION_ID).Title("REG_ID").Hidden(true);
            column.Bound(e => e.TariffType).Title("TariffType").Hidden(true);
            column.Bound(e => e.BILL_GENERATED).Title("Bill generated");
            column.Bound(e => e.D0071_SEND).Title("D0071_SEND");
            column.Bound(e => e.ROLECODE).Title("ROLECODE").Hidden(true);
        }
    )
```

I want to use the Kendo Grid column with jQuery.

```
function SendflowAutomatically() {
    debugger;
    var RegIDs = [];
    $("#ApproveCustomerMeterRead").find("input:checked").each(function() {
        RegIDs.push($(this).val().toString().trim());
    });
    ///
    if (difference between settlement_date_regi and meter_read_date < 5) //how to use kendo columns here.
    {
        // do something

    } else {
        // format here
    }

}
```

I have tried doing this:

```
//tried using this//
var rows = e.sender.tbody.children();
for (var j = 0; j < rows.length; j++) {
    var row = $(rows[j]);
    var dataItem = e.sender.dataItem(row);
    if (dataItem.get("CreatedDate")) {
        $(this).DoTheFormatting...
    }
}
```

Comment: It appears "CreatedDate" isn't in your example model. Could it be that field doesnt exist, and thats why what you tried didn't work?

Comment: @AussieJoe hi,Aussie my issue lies in if condition.How to use kendo grid column in if condition